# Putting Opera tab manager on the most top?

Tags: opera

How I can remove top margin of Opera tab manager and put it in the most top position?

[image: Opera Tab Manager Screenshot]

In fact, this is most annoying thing about Opera for me! Thanks :)

**Edit:**
This is for Opera till version 12. For newer versions of Opera (> 15), have a look at [Push Opera tabs all the way to the top](https://superuser.com/questions/657998/putting-opera-tab-manager-on-the-most-top-chromium-engine-based-opera) [as the time of editing still not answered]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two settings for that margin (depending on whether the Opera window is maximized or not):

```
opera:config#UserPrefs|ChromeIntegrationDragArea
opera:config#UserPrefs|ChromeIntegrationDragAreaMaximized
```

If you set these to `0`, you can completely eliminate the top margin. Personally, I like to have a 1-pixel margin on top, so that I can drag and move Opera when it's maximized in Win7 and to have access to the window menu, but that's just me.

To edit them, follow these steps:

1. Go to the Preferences Editor by entering `opera:config` in the address bar.
2. Type `chrome` in the Quick Find field to locate and edit them.
3. Click the Save button. If you resize the Opera window you should see the changes take effect.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, +1. I think you might've left out an instruction between 2 and 3 though, to adjust the values before saving ;-)