# Push Opera tabs all the way to the top

Tags: opera

How can I push the tabs on Opera's tab manager all the way to the top, and remove that pixel space of padding it has up there?

Example ([taken from Presto engine version of this question](https://superuser.com/questions/509354/putting-opera-tab-manager-on-the-most-top))

[image: Opera Tab Manager Screenshot]

I'm asking about the Chromium engine-based version of Opera.

How do I do this?

Comment: So which version of Opera are you asking about?

Comment: Right now i'm asking about Opera 17

Comment: As the questioner of the original question wanted thank you for asking it! :) Hope we find an answer for it.

Comment: Tnx for support in question :) finally i found answer! in setting opera have option which do exactly

Disable tab bar's top spacing when browser window is maximized

Answer (score 2):

**SETTING**

```
User interface
Disable tab bar's top spacing when browser window is maximized
```

Comment: I wish this was also possible for non-maximized.

Comment: Just in case when you can't find this option - you should check "Show advanced settings" option at the bottom of the settings page.